# Windows change password

Tags: windows, passwords

Is there a way to change password from CMD line without Admin rights?

I know old password, I just want to change password by script, where I can not use UI.

Using net user   I know, but this is password reset and this will invalidate secure store, which I would like to not to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure store"? Do you mean [EFS credentials recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc512680(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)? There aren't two ways for changing the password, so all the methods are equivalent.

Comment: @harrymc: Password reset invalidates everything that's protected by DPAPI – including EFS keypairs, any other certificates/keypairs, stored network passwords ("Windows Credential Manager"), as well as custom data that programs sent through CryptProtectData.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: That doesn't really help with understanding the user's concern.

Comment: @harrymc: The thing is that there _are_ two ways for changing the password: one that takes the old password as input (NetUserChangePassword), and one that doesn't (NetUserSetInfo). The methods that accept the old password count as a "password change" and retain all DPAPI data; the ones which don't are a "password reset" and lose the data, as well as being admin-only.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: There are more than two methods, depending on the context, but that's beside the point here.

Comment: @harrymc: No, I think that's very much the point; they are _not_ all equivalent.

Comment: **Before** you reset a Windows users password, understand the only way NOT to effect files encrypted with EFS, is to change the password as the user. If you **reset** the pass you will absolutely lose access to those encrypted files. The only way of NOT effecting encrypted files is by knowing and utilizing your current password in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [NetUserChangePassword()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserchangepassword) function from Netapi32.dll, e.g. via PowerShell:

1. Import external function (uses C# [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetUserChangePassword) syntax):

   ```
   $netapi32 = Add-Type -PassThru -Name NetAPI32 -MemberDefinition @'
       [DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
       public static extern bool NetUserChangePassword(string DomainName,
                                                       string UserName,
                                                       string OldPassword,
                                                       string NewPassword);
   '@
   ```
2. Perform the change:

   ```
   $netapi32::NetUserChangePassword($env:USERDOMAIN,
                                    $env:USERNAME,
                                    "OldPassword",
                                    "NewPassword")
   ```

(Code not tested; mostly copied from [an earlier ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/570501/5799).)

For local accounts, the DomainName can be either `.` or the local computer name.

This is from the same family of functions as used by `net`, and should work with any traditional account type, including local and Active Directory accounts. I'm not sure whether it works with Azure AD accounts.

Comment: Should work with AzureAD if you specify the user as AzureAD\username@domain.ext